# MySQL select with mutliple variables in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I want to use the following kind of SELECT from a python scrip, with 2 variables:

- list with ids
- count

something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM servers 
 WHERE id IN (32, 48, 49, 68) 
 GROUP 
    BY serial 
 ORDER 
    BY first_seen 
 LIMIT 4;
```

the number of the IDs in the "IN" will change, and also the "limit" based on the number of serves. (in this example I have 4 server id and because of this the limit is also 4)

I tried the following (this is one scenario):

---

```
list_serial_client = (24,347,359,360,362,363,365,418,388,23)


my_string = ','.join(map(str, list_serial_client)) 
count = len(list_serial_client)

tuple = ((my_string), count)
print(tuple)

q="""SELECT \
i.id,s.serial, i.persistent_uuid, b.id, u.patchnum, u.first_seen \
FROM  installs i LEFT JOIN serials s ON  s.hardware_id = i.hardware_id \
LEFT JOIN updates u ON u.install_id = i.id \
LEFT JOIN buildnumbers b ON b.image_uuid = u.image_uuid \
WHERE s.serial IN (%s) \
AND i.invalidated IS NULL GROUP BY s.serial, u.first_seen \
ORDER BY first_seen DESC LIMIT %s"""

mycursor.execute(q, tuple)

for x in mycursor:
    print(" >>  " + str(x))
```

unfortunately it reurns only with rows for the first ID (24 in this example), and also ignores the limit

```
 >>  (44, 24, 'cdc9fd8d-6899-4d9c-89c3-3b71b2dd88c5', 144, 831)
 >>  (44, 24, 'cdc9fd8d-6899-4d9c-89c3-3b71b2dd88c5', 124, 448)
 >>  (44, 24, 'cdc9fd8d-6899-4d9c-89c3-3b71b2dd88c5', 106, 448)
 >>  (44, 24, 'cdc9fd8d-6899-4d9c-89c3-3b71b2dd88c5', 7, 448)
```

the output of the print(tuple) is this:
`('24,347,359,360,362,363,365,418,388,23', 10)`

I want to have the "24,347,359,360,362,363,365,418,388,23" in the IN() part, and the 10 at the LIMIT

thank you

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [string.format](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) like shown below:

```
>>> q = 'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id IN {} GROUP BY serial ORDER BY first_seen LIMIT {};'
>>> list_serial_client =  (32, 48, 49, 68) 
>>> limit = len(list_serial_client)
>>> mysql_query = q.format(list_serial_client, limit)
>>> mysql_query
'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id IN (32, 48, 49, 68) GROUP BY serial ORDER BY first_seen LIMIT 4;'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> list_serial_client =  (32, 48, 49, 68) 
>>> limit = len(list_serial_client)
>>> mysql_query = f'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id IN {list_serial_client} GROUP BY serial ORDER BY first_seen LIMIT {limit};'
>>> mysql_query
'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id IN (32, 48, 49, 68) GROUP BY serial ORDER BY first_seen LIMIT 4;'
>>>
```